# Split Array in Objects in Java

Tags: java, stream

I'm stuck in splitting an array in a sub array in an object. I have the following:

Input/Output AClass:

```
 {
    attribute1: 'value1',
    attribute2: 'value2',
    // etc.
    assets: [
      {assetAttribute1: 'value1', // etc.},
      {assetAttribute2: 'value2', // etc.}
      // etc.
    ]
  }
```

Stream Input:

```
inputs = [
     {
        attribute1: 'value1',
        attribute2: 'value2',
        assets: [
          {assetAttribute1: 'value1', // etc.},
          {assetAttribute2: 'value2', // etc.}
          // etc.
        ]
      },
    
    ]
```

Expected stream output:

```
outputs = [
     {
        attribute1: 'value1', // same as from the input
        attribute2: 'value2', // same as from the input
        assets: [
          {assetAttribute1: 'value1', // etc.} // input asset array index 0
        ]
      },
      {
        attribute1: 'value1', // same as from the input
        attribute2: 'value2', // same as from the input
        assets: [
          {assetAttribute2: 'value2', // etc.} // // input asset array index 1
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Code:

```
KStream<String, AClass> inputs = //...
KStream<String, AClass> output = inputs.map((key, aclass) -> {
                return aclass.getAssets().stream().map(asset -> {
                    AClass transform = new AClass();
                    transform = aclass.clone();
                    transform.setAssets(Arrays.asList(asset));
                    return new KeyValue<String, AClass>(key, miaTransitAsset);
                });
            });
```

As you see this can not work. But I'm now stuck how I could achieve that with the Java Streams. You can ignore the kafka stream as it basically the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fps Thanks for your question. No, that's completely dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is manageable to do it with one stream however, for readability let mi split this fist:

For simplicity, I created myself a class (hopefully got it right from the JSON description):

```
class Input {
    String attribute1;
    String attribute2;
    List<Map<String, String>> assets;

    public Input(String attribute1, String attribute2, List<Map<String, String>> assets) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.assets = assets;
    }
}
```

Then some dumb initialization to have some data to work on:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> assets = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> attributeMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> attributeMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    attributeMap1.put("assetAttribute1", "value1");
    attributeMap2.put("assetAttribute2", "value2");

    assets.add(attributeMap1);
    assets.add(attributeMap2);
    Input input = new Input("value1", "value2", assets);

    List<Input> inputs = Arrays.asList(input);
```

And here come the lambdas:

First, you have to get all the attributes you want to extract (list of assets over which you will create new objects):

```
List<Map<String, String>> extractedAssets = inputs
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.assets)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then for each of these assets, you need a copy of what you had in input previously, but with the difference of "assets" list content. So the best way is to create a new object for each previously extractedAsset:

```
List<Input> collect = extractedAssets.stream()
            .map(e -> new Input(
                    input.attribute1,
                    input.attribute2,
                    Collections.singletonList(e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This should work :)

Or with one stream:

```
List<Input> collect1 = inputs.
            stream()
            .map(e -> e.assets)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(e -> new Input(
                    inputs.get(0).attribute1,
                    inputs.get(0).attribute2,
                    Collections.singletonList(e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The only thing I don't get from there you get the input.* in the map(e ->
That's missing right?

Comment: Well, actually it is in this data initialization block I pasted (the second from the bottom), however, for your application you should rather have something like inputs[0].getAttribute1, inputs[0].getAttribute2 ...  :)

I'll edit the answer because it might be misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now it's clear. I have now found another way via forEach. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Przemysław Gęsieniec. You inspired me to think in another direction and I think I found now a way:

```
KStream<String, AClass> output = inputs.flatMap(
            (key,value) -> {
                List<KeyValue<String, AClass>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                value.getAssets().forEach(asset -> {
                    AClass transform = value.clone();
                    transform.setAssets(Arrays.asList(asset));
                    result.add(KeyValue.pair(key, transform));
                });
                return result;
            });
```